# Android GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR backport

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Does any one know if it is possible to backport GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR to Android 4.x?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could reimplement one based on accelerometer and gyroscope data. It's not straightforward though. You can search for "orientation kalman filter" and see if there is an implementation for Android. If you find one that works well, please let us know!

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing platform code that you could easily backport, as the computation for these sensor values is done at the native layer ([here's](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android_hardware_SensorManager.cpp) the JNI code, and [here's](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/hardware/SystemSensorManager.java#L377) the Java implementation for Sensor Manager that receives the sensor event updates from native code).

So, depending on your use case, your best bet may be to use the [TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) sensor on Android 4.X, since according to the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR) the TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR is:

> A constant describing an uncalibrated rotation vector sensor type.
>
> Identical to TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR except that it doesn't use the geomagnetic field. Therefore the Y axis doesn't point north, but instead to some other reference, that reference is allowed to drift by the same order of magnitude as the gyroscope drift around the Z axis.
>
> In the ideal case, a phone rotated and returning to the same real-world orientation should report the same game rotation vector (without using the earth's geomagnetic field). However, the orientation may drift somewhat over time.

You could then transform the Y axis manually according to some other reference, which would work as long as the ideal case above holds.  However, if the sensor starts to drift, then your transformation would start to accumulate errors.